# cross compilation. set last location to search for libraries

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling, static-linking

Currently I am making a cross compilation for arm using the arm-none-eabi tool-chain. after the object files are created using GNU compiler, at the final stage I use arm linker to link the object files and scatter files together. The problem is that during compilation the compiler adds symbols like

```
__gxx_personality_v0     (implementation in libstdc++)
__impure_ptr             (implementation in libc)
__ctype_ptr__            (implementation in libc)
__assert_func            (implementation in libc)
```

I want libc and libstdc++ libraries to be searched at the end when linking, so that other implementations e.g malloc, printf are linked with arm libraries. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: List the *arm libraries* first and the linker will resolve them.  Note: that these symbols could possibly use other functions in the *libc*.  From brief inspection, I don't think this is the case, but you should look at the *libc* source to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched through the header files and saw their definitions. I added their definition in my project header files and the compilation completed